# Get Index of Selected GridViewItem in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

I want to get index of selected CridViewItem and store it in a  variable. This is my function selecte Item. How can i do it. Help me please. Thks

I create a variable named itemLocation for store index

```
private void gridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    App.SomeImportantValue = Tabs;
    myFrame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var value = Gridview.SelectedItem
```